# Avoid expansion of `\marginpar` argument

Tags: expansion, marginpar

I'm trying to make a margin par that will show the value of some macro defined *after* the placement point of the marginpar (think of it as something like `\footnotemark` vs `\footnotetext`).

However, the `\marginpar` command seems to fully expand its argument and I cannot get the desired behavior with any combination of `\noexpand` and similar.

Here is a little example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\def\mymacro{Content}
Some text. \marginpar{\mymacro}

\def\mymacro{Other content}

Some other text.

\end{document}
```

Here I would like the marginpar to display the text "Other content". If I put `\noexpand` before `\mymacro` in the `\marginpar` argument, I get no marginpar at all, which is strange.

Of course there has to be a limit on how far the definition has to be, because I cannot delay the expansion further than the execution of the page shipout code (although I'm only vaguely familiar with how the mechanism works). But in the case of this example I'd expect it to be possible.

Is it possible to get `\marginpar` to not expand immediately its argument?

Comment: How should that be possible? `\marginpar` inserts something right when it is called, and does not wait till the end of the document, say.

Comment: That's why I put the `expansion` tag on the question. I suppose in some way it should be possible to delay the expansion of the macro until it gets actually typeset. Unless \marginpar is typesetting the content right away and saving it as a box. Is this the case?

Comment: Well, you can try to do something with atbegshi or so. What I wanted to say is that a plain `\marginpar` won't do it.

Comment: I don't understand why. I see it simply as a matter of when the argument of `\marginpar` is expanded.

Comment: marginpars like floats and footnotes are fully typeset at the point they are entered, like `\savebox` they are placed on the page like `\usebox` which just copies a typeset formatted list, no expansion happens at that time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

marginpars like floats and footnotes are fully typeset at the point they are entered, like `\savebox` they are placed on the page like `\usebox` which just copies a typeset formatted list, no expansion happens at that time

if you put `\noexpand` before your macro then you have

```
\marginpar{\noexpand\mymacro}
```

which is exactly the same as

```
\marginpar{\relax}
```

so you get an empty marginpar. (But it is actually there, LaTeX still goes to the trouble of placing it in the margin, but it has no content)

As always, if you want text to depend on a forward reference depending on which  page it is finally typeset, then you can use or abuse `\label`/`\ref`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}



Some text. \marginpar{\ref{foo}}

{\makeatletter\def\@currentlabel{Other content}\label{foo}}

Some other text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that explains a lot of things! So abusing `\label` is just a way of using the `.aux` file, right?

Comment: @gigabytes yes.